# Why does VSCode Python code completion not work for my firestore client variable?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I have the following python snippet...

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate("./cert.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

client = firestore.client()
client.
```

When I type the dot on the last line, no code completion options come up. On the 'firestore' variable, there are code completion options that come up.

I have the Python and Pylance extensions installed in VSCode. Is this a configuration issue, or is there something about what the client() method is returning, that it is not possible to infer its type?

Comment: I would have to guess the latter. What does it show when you hover over `.client()`?

Comment: Is `firestore.client` a class or a function?

Comment: Its a class. Apparently it returns this...https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/admin_client#class-googlecloudfirestoreadminv1servicesfirestoreadminclientfirestoreadminclient-credentials-optionalgoogleauthcredentialscredentials--none-transport-optionalunionstr-googlecloudfirestoreadminv1servicesfirestoreadmintransportsbasefirestoreadmintransport--none-clientoptions-optionaluniongoogleapicoreclientoptionsclientoptions-dict--none-clientinfo-googleapicoregapicv1clientinfoclientinfo--googleapicoregapicv1clientinfoclientinfo-object

Comment: It seems that it cannot recognize the client (), and the returned type is still any.

Comment: Is there some kind of bug I could submit to firebase if their library is broke?

Comment: @Scorb Sure, I suggest you submitting the problem to the developer of this package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was already [an open issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/issues/626) for this on the github repo, which also included a temporary (poor) workaround.

```
from firebase_admin import firestore
from google.cloud.firestore import Client as FirestoreClient # importing the return type of firestore.client()
db: FirestoreClient = firestore.client() # Adding an annotation to my db variable, to enable completion and syntax checking
```

Comment: Thanks perfectly works, but is it still necessary in 2023??